# Pocket Edition "disconnected from server" every few minutes in realms

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When me and my friends are in my minecraft pocket edition realm every few minutes it kicks us out and says "disconnected from server" and we have to wait like a while for it to let us back in.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem for the last two weeks now. Mojang support say it is *probably* a problem with the world and to reset it. ( They have zero access to the servers - I confirmed this with them in an email ). So I reset the world and it still doesn't work.

Here is the reply from **help@mojang.com**:

***"This help centre is mostly limited to accounts and billing. We can't troubleshoot worlds, but if no one can connect to it, the world is likely the issue."***

I then got a refund and signed up for another incase it was a problem specific to the server my first realm was on. Again, after a few days it crashed. My friend who has Android can get on to the realm periodically but when I try it always crashes and kicks them off.

So, I then tried minecraft on my iPad and also on Windows 10 thinking it might be to do with the device or iOS build. Same result every time.

It's ridiculous that mojang/microsoft provide these realms without any way to back them up. The PC/Full MC Version realms have auto backups so this is obviously something that does occur.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mojang's realm server is at very high traffic and it cannot handle all players.

Answer (score 0):

Now in 0.15, u can play minecraft PE realms smoothly after u signed in to XBox Live Minecraft.

Comment: This... Sounds less lika an answer and more like an advertisement.

Comment: Ok sorry sorry 

Answer (score -1):

Same happens to me. It disconnects when there is a block that's destroyed in a specific place. If it continues I recommend not messing with it.